# Is there an alternative to Box's M test for data that is not multivariate normally distributed?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

My research question is to test whether two groups have a difference in variance-covariance across multiple measures. However, the data do not follow the multivariate normality assumption required for Box's M and the sample size is relatively modest at 30 per group. Is there an alternative in this case?

I have found some suggestions by [Layard](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2239905.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A6d84e9cddb514c85b8e9b9e13f80b73f), but few implementations in practice and there is some criticism in the literature. I also found [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2018.1497537) useful summary on visualisation of tests for equality of Covariance Matrices by M. Friendly and M. Sigal.

Comment: You also might want to consider if “correlation” if the right kind of dependence structure to consider. Without multivariate normality, you could have a funky but interesting dependence structure. This is related to something called the copula.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. That's an interesting additional question to consider, I hadn't thought about that!

Comment: @Dave, how to apply the copula theory as alternative to Box's M test here?

Comment: @Nick I would start by hitting the marginal distributions with the probability integral transform (ecdf(x)(x) in R) and plotting to see what kind of relationship there is.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X08001474 Optimal tests for homogeneity of covariance, scale, and shape

Comment: I am reading description of the package ‘ICSNP’ as
Tools for Multivariate Nonparametrics.

Comment: @readbeard, maybe useful for you https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-September/079210.html

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I'll take a look at the links.